# Kendo-Ui Mobile Define style per platform

Tags: styles, themes, kendo-mobile

How can I define in my application platform specific default style like

- for Android    : Android Light
- for ios        : flat
- for ios7       : ios7
- for blackberry : flat
- for wp         : flat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no integrated way to do this, but you can make some platform checks - use [kendo.support.mobileOS](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo#fields-support.mobileOS) and the [skin config option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/application#configuration-skin).